# “Include” one javascript file to another one in serverside environment or in commandline environment

Tags: javascript, ios5, cmd

I have one **"Test1.js"** JavaScript file which will be running continuously. I have another **"Test2.js"** JavaScript file which I will update periodically. I want to call a dynamically created Test2.js JavaScript function from Test1.js file.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: If I understand your goal correctly, you have Test1.js running all the time and you want to "inject" changes of Test2.js, without stopping Test1.js? I'm a bit confused with ios5 tag, not sure why you would put that here...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes @maremp, you are right I want to implement the same. Basically I am launching Test1.js file from iOS code. That's why I added iOS there. Please let me know how I can implement this. I'm searching this from long time.

Comment: Is there any one who can help me.

Comment: Where is your code running? I don't think I understand this correctly, how does your 'launching from iOS code' look like? Some code would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You should require functions after when all scripts will be upload.
So, for example in **Test1.js**

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    bar();
}, false);
```

In **Test2.js**

```
function bar() {
    alert('This is function BAR');
}
```

Comment: Title says server side environment... server-side (e.g. node) doesn't have such thing as window. And this wouldn't even work when Test2.js changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes it is server side and not client side.